# How to create multiple threads for the completion port?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, iocp

Multiple threads can dequeue completion packets from a single completion port using the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` function. Is there a special function that creates these threads? Or I simply use for example `CreateThread()` or `_beginthreadex()` and create as much threads as I need?

Comment: You can either create the completion port yourself and use `CreateThread` or equivalent, or you can let the thread pool take care of it all: [CreateThreadpoolIo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Harry Johnston So if I want to create 4 threads that waits on the completion port, I would just call `CreateThread()` 4 times? Also, I would guess that I should use `_beginthreadex()` and not `CreateThread()`, correct?

Comment: (1) yes.  (2) It doesn't really matter any more except as a matter of style.  Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: Actually it's far more than a matter of style. You MUST use `_beginthreaex()` if you use the c runtime otherwise key library components will not be initialised correctly until they are first used and this may cause problems in low memory situations (see the docs for `CreateThread()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about a thread that calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` on a given IOCP. Any thread can do it. Therefore you can create your "I/O threads" using the usual thread creation functions. In general it's best to use `_beginthreadex()` unless you're writing code for platforms that do not support it OR you are not linking with the CRT.